Looking for a film about kids whose parents die when their house burns down and they have an evil uncle who wants their fortune
Two kids (brother and sister) get their house burnt down and parents die so they have to move in with different family members but each family gets killed by an evil uncle or something that wants to inherit the money, but he struggles to kill the kids. I remember the little girl with the Most Dangerous Snake in the world is the most friendly. And one other one where the House falls off the cliff, and the lady gets pushed into the water full of piranhas.

FYI it looks like the may be a TV version being made by netflicks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xer4VCa5-tg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Series_of_Unfortunate_Events#TV_series

Marking it as a duplicate as this is at least the 3rd time this came up in ID.

You're looking for the 2004 film based on a series of books called Lemony Snicket's A Series of Unfortunate Events.
The story is exactly as you describe (well, there's three kids but one is a toddler, so we can pretend she doesn't exist):

Violet Baudelaire (Emily Browning), her intelligent brother Klaus (Liam Aiken), and their baby sister Sunny (Kara and Shelby Hoffman) are orphaned when a mysterious fire destroys their house. Mr. Poe (Timothy Spall), in charge of the Baudelaire fortune, entrusts them to their closest relative, Count Olaf (Jim Carrey), who only wants their money and makes them do harsh chores.

The snake:

Violet tries to tell Monty the truth, but he thinks Stephano is after a snake called The Incredible Deadly Viper. Monty is found dead the next day and authorities have been tricked into thinking the viper was responsible, but Sunny is able to prove it is actually a gentle creature. 

And I think you mean leaches instead of piranhas:

After Sailing Lake Lachrymose the children find Josephine, but before they reach civilization their boat is attacked by leeches, and Olaf appears, and kills Josephine by pushing her into the waters after she corrects his grammar.

Here's the trailer:



